# Regex to match X...X...Y?

Tags: regex

I've been looking for a while, but I don't know how to describe this well enough to google it. I'm trying to find the string "X...X...Y", where X is some regex clause, but I can't figure out how to say "match what matched my first clause" to ensure that the second occurrence of X doesn't just match the regex clause, but exactly matches what just satisfied the first clause.

Basically, it'll look something like `(*) != nil ? (*) : (*)`, but I want to match `"a != nil ? a : b"`, not `"a != nil ? b : c"`

**EDIT**
The term I was looking for was "back-references", see linked answer (mine's a dup) for more info

Comment: In case you are searching for something related to regular expressions, you are almost sure to find it at http://regular-expressions.info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and a [back-reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) to it.

Here is an example:

```
(a).*\1.*b
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kM0pQ3/1)

We match `a` and place it in the capturing group 1, then we match some characters with `.*` (or none), then we check what we matched with `(a)` (it was `a`), and then again any characters and `b`.

Mind that in real-world, we often have to use word boundaries to match whole words, e.g.

```
\b(a)\b.*\1.*\bb\b
```

This way, we won't match `a` and `b` in `abc`, but a "standalone" `a` and `b`.

**Instead of `a` or `b`, you can use any patterns, shorthand classes, and whole sequences of subpatterns.**

Comment: Just wondering, can you backreference a non-capturing group?

Comment: No, a non-capturing group is not meant to be back-referenced.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about back-references, for example in Python this yields `[007, 223, 445]`:

```
data = [i.group() for i in re.finditer(r'(\d)\1\d', '007 123 223 445 789')]
```